# Json keeping added keys together without creating new dicts

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to keep keys that are added together. I have written this little script which adds key and value every time its run but it keeps adding dicts.

```
import json
import datetime

key = str(datetime.datetime.now())
insert = 'Test'
logged = {key : insert}

data = json.load(open('StartLog.json', 'r'))
with open('StartLog.json', 'w') as f:
    data['Logs'].append(logged)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

The output currently would be:

```
{
  "Logs": [
    {
      "2018-08-28 22:07:12.540188": "Test"
    },
    {
      "2018-08-28 22:07:20.134817": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like the output to be:

```
{
  "Logs": [
    {
      "2018-08-28 22:07:12.540188": "Test",
      "2018-08-28 22:07:20.134817": "Test"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Logs` within `data` to a dictionary and update the dict with each entry:

```
import json
import datetime

key = str(datetime.datetime.now())
insert = 'Test'
logged = {key : insert}

data = json.load(open('StartLog.json', 'r'))
with open('StartLog.json', 'w') as f:
    data['Logs'].update(logged)
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

So `StartLog.json` should start as:

```
{
  "Logs": {
  }
}
```